# How do you traverse a HTML document, search, and skip to the next item using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

How do you traverse up to a certain found element and then continue to the next found item? In my example I am trying to search for the first  element, grab the text, and then continue until I find the next  tag or until I hit a specific  tag. The reason I need to also take into account the  tag is because I want to do something there.

Html

```
<table border=0>
  <tr> 
    <td width=180>
      <font size=+1><b>apple</b></font>
    </td>
    <td>Description of an apple</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td width=180>
      <font size=+1><b>banana</b></font>
    </td>
    <td>Description of a banana</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td><img vspace=4 hspace=0 src="common/dot_clear.gif"></td>
  </tr>
...Then this repeats itself in a similar format
```

Current scrape.rb

```
#...
document.at_css("body").traverse do |node|
  #if <font> is found 
    #puts text in font
  #else if <img> is found then 
    #puts img src and continue loop until end of document
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: Give a properly arranged HTML code, then expected output you are looking for, with some samples.

Comment: Sorry, how do I make it easier to read and please correct me if I hae html tag issues? I condensed it down to make it easier to understand. Basically I am having issues traversing and there aren't too many examples online.

Comment: Your question isn't clear and sounds like an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What is your goal, what do you really want to do? Traversing all nodes of a document is rarely the right action.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. You basically want to traverse through all the *children* in your tree and perform some operations on basis of the nodes obtained.

So here is how we can do that:

```
#Acquiring dummy page
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29'))
```

Now, if you want to start traversing all `body` elements, we can employ `XPath` for our rescue. XPath expression: `//body//*` will give back all the *children* and *grand-children* in `body`.

This would return the array of elements with class `Nokogiri::XML::Element`

```
page.xpath('//body//*')
page.xpath('//body//*').first.node_name
#=> "div"
```

So, you can now traverse on that array and perform your operations:

```
page.xpath('//body//*').each do |node|
  case node.name
    when 'div' then #do this 
    when 'font' then #do that
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```
document.at_css("body").traverse do |node|
  if node.name == 'font'
    puts node.content
  elsif node.name == 'img'
    puts node.attribute("src") 
end
```